# E-mail reporting issue for RAID on DELL servers

Tags: email, raid, dell, reporting

On the server of one of our clients, we have a problem with the implementation of email reporting for RAID in the DELL server. I know that if such a server has an iDRAC port, such reporting can be performed.
However, the server that has the client has no such port.

This is the **DELL PowerEdge T330** server.

I tried reporting with:

1. Intel Rapid Storage Enterprise and Email Relay, but the problem here was that in Intel RSTe you could not see the disks, which is inconvenient for us.
2. DELL EMC OpenManage Server Administrator and Email Relay, but the problem here was that what settings I would not use, reporting did not work.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to do email reporting for RAID in DELL servers without iDRAC port? If so, how?
2. Is there anyone who has managed to do email reporting for RAID using DELL EMC OMSA, Email Relay, Intel RSTe (with a version where disks will be visible)?

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using megacli tools directly on the server's os and see if you are able to detect the raid? or whatever cli software that your controller might use? I have a Dell with a Perc H700 raid controller and I use megacli tools to check controller status, arrays and so on

Comment: Unfortunately, we prefer pure software. The boss disapproves of CLI too much.

Comment: I just aprroved :) as I'm the boss.

Comment: The only thing I found for this server is it is marked in this photo https://imgur.com/a/LAYlzIR